# Carrierwave, Dropzone.js Rails 4, Strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave, strong-parameters, dropzone.js

I am trying to upload multiple images using Carrierwave and Dropzone.js however I am getting following error when I submit the form.

Please note that the same form without dropzone.js is working fine, meaning when I am simply using HTML5 to upload multiple images.

Please see below hash which is created when I submit the form (through ajax using dropzone)

---

"project_images_attributes"=>[{"image"=

> [#, @original_filename="artist4.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"project[project_
>   images_attributes][][image][]\"; filename=\"artist4.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #, @original_filename="feed1.jpg", @con
>   tent_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"project[project_images_attributes][][image][]\"; filename=\"feed1.jpg\"\
>   r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, #, @original_filename="gallery1.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: 
>   form-data; name=\"project[project_images_attributes][][image][]\"; filename=\"gallery1.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">]}]}, "project-vide
>   o"=>[""], "commit"=>"Create project"}

**Unpermitted parameters: image**

Please note I have whitelisted the image params in my controller and also it's working using HTML 5 but not using ajax and dropzone.js

Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Thank you

Comment: Share the relevant code from the controller where you have whitelisted the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Code to contextualize where I ended up:

```
  private
  def pin_image_params
    #params.require(:pin_image).permit(:photo) (not permitted)
    #params.require(:pin_image).permit(photo: [:'0']) (permitted but action handler error)
    #params.require(:pin_image)["photo"].values.first (stringify_keys error)
    params.require(:photos).values
  end
```

The strong params kept returning unpermitted params :photo. Looking in console, I saw that the params were getting numbered, and the only way I could access them was to dive in by number. Even then though, trying to pass them in directly to `create` returned errors. This was because the model can't understand the format of the numbered hash. It's not smart enough to know it needs to iterate through each attached image. So:

```
def create
   # so pin_image_params is an array of files basically
   @pin_images = pin_image_params.inject([]) do |memo, photo|
   # this pattern will store the memo into the @pin_images reference
      memo << PinImage.create(photo: photo)
   # keying it explicitly
   end
   if @pin_images.present?
      render json: { id: @pin_images.map(&:id) }, :status => 200
   else
      #  you need to send an error header, otherwise Dropzone
      #  will not interpret the response as an error:
      render json: { error: @pin_images.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
   end
end
```

My controller returns a list of ids, and those are captured in a hidden field for the model that owns PinImage (Pin). (That's done in a success callback on the ajax that submits the PinImages via dropzone.) So when the primary model is submitted, I also have to handle doing the association there, but I find I am preferring that to muddling through nested_attributes_for. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the way you submit your form. Is it form.submit? Dropzone automatically submits the file through ajax once uploading is finished